# Solving an equation with a function

Tags: functional-equations

So the problem is to find $f(x)$ such that:
$$f(x+1)-f(x)=1/(x+1)$$

I have found that $\ln x$ is a good approximation for large values of $x$.

$f(x)$ not differentiable at $x=-1$.

Comment: This is called a functional equation.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that there might be more than one function satisfying this. For instance, both the functions $x$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ satisfy $f(x+1)-f(x)=1$.

Comment: This equation is undefined for $x=-1$ so you should say exactly for what values of $x$ the equation needs to hold. Note that adding a constant to a solution gives us another solution.

Comment: $f(x)=\psi(x+1)+C$ would be a solution, where $\psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization).

Comment: You shouldn't write $F(x)$ if you mean $f(x). \qquad$

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple recurrence, that can be written

$$f(x)=f(x-1)+\frac1x.$$

By induction,

$$f(x)=f(x-n)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{x-k}.$$

If we assume the initial condition that $f$ is known in $[0,1)$, we have

$$f(x)=f(\{x\})+\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor-1}\frac1{x-k}.$$

For large $x$, it indeeds tends to an Harmonic series, with a perturbation term.

Comment: What about a function not only for integers. Such that f: R-->R

Comment: @NickThyname: this is precisely what my answer is. I guess that you didn't understand it.

Comment: No. I havent. So there is no neat solution?

Comment: @NickThyname Whether there is a "neat solution" depends on your initial conditions and on what you consider "neat."

Comment: @NickThyname: I gave you a quite general, neat solution.